# Remove specific rows that contain dates Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that has datetime values in it. I would like to remove all rows within a specific column that contain a certain year. All rows that contain 2027 should be removed.

**Data**

```
ID  Date                Type
AA  2027-04-03 00:00:00 ok
AA  2027-05-06 00:00:00 no
BB  2027-07-05 00:00:00 yes
BB  2026-06-05 00:00:00 yes
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Date                Type
BB  2026-06-05 00:00:00 yes
```

**Doing**

```
df1 = df[df["Date"].str.contains("-2027") == False]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Error:
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

I believe I need to do some type of conversion here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the data is already a datetime type, str accessor fails. Following should resolve it

```
df1=df[df["Date"].dt.year != 2027]
```

```
    ID  Date    Type
3   BB  2026-06-05  yes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the column date to a string and apply your code:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
df1 = df[df["Date"].str.contains("2027") == False]
```

Answer (score 1):

Corse date to datetime, extract year and check if equal to 2027

```
df[pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year==2027]
```